# Finding dependecies amongst JARs

Tags: java, jar

We are in process of migrating our project from Ant to Maven. While doing this migration we are facing difficulties in finding dependencies between jars that are used in Ant. I just want to know main jars which are needed to mention in `pom.xml` and the remaining jars will be automatically downloaded.

In short I want to know how to find dependecies amongst JAR files used in our project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a tool from  JBoss project called [JBoss TattleTale](http://tattletale.jboss.org/), might be worth taking a look:

The tool will provide you  lot more then just dependencies finding :

- Identify dependencies between JAR files
- Find missing classes from the classpath
- Spot if a class/package is located in multiple JAR files
- Spot if the same JAR file is located in multiple locations
- With a list of what each JAR file requires and provides
- Verify the SerialVersionUID of a class
- Find similar JAR files that have different version numbers
- Find JAR files without a version number
- Find unused JAR archives
- Identify sealed / signed JAR archives
- Locate a class in a JAR file
- Get the OSGi status of your project
- Remove black listed API usage
- And generate the same reports for your .WAR and .EAR archives

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use [jarAnalyzer](http://www.kirkk.com/main/Main/JarAnalyzer#What) which will traverse through each of the jar files in that directory specified, and identify the dependencies between the jar files. The output will be xml representing the dependencies between two jar files.